# java script whack a mole, dynamically removing mole

Tags: javascript

I am not sure how to remove a mole at a random timed interval, any thoughts? the instructions are..One of the few tasks which remains is to make the randomly appearing moles, disappear at random! Each randomly added mole should also disappear after a separately random time.

```
   function timeDecrease(){
   $("#timer").show();
   $("#timer").html(time + " seconds left")
   time -= 1;
   if (time >0)
     {
      t = setTimeout("timeDecrease()",1000);
     }
     else time = 0;
     };

function randomMole(min,max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};
 function addMole(){

   yPos = getY();
   xPos = getX();

   $("#gamespace").append('<img class= "Image" img src="img/mole.png" 
   style ="top:'+yPos+'px; bottom: 
  '+xPos+'px;left:'+xPos+'px;right:'+yPos+'px;"/>');
   moreMoles = setTimeout(addMole,randomMole(0,2000));
```

Comment: Everyone seems to be creating one of these nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

In your `addMole` function, store a reference to the new mole and set a timer to remove it.

```
let newMole = $(`<img
                   class="Image"
                   src="img/mole.png"
                   style="top: ${yPos}px; left: ${xPos}px;"
                 >`);
$("#gamespace").append(newMole);
setTimeout(newMole.remove.bind(newMole), randomMole(1000, 2000));
moreMoles = setTimeout(addMole,randomMole(0,2000));
```

We use [template literals](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-template-strings-in-depth) because they hurt less than concatenating strings. `newMole.remove()` would remove the new mole from the DOM, but calling it as a `setTimeout` callback won't work. It would be called by `window`, so the `this` keyword would be set to `window`, but jQuery expects `this` to be set to the element you're removing. `newMole.remove.bind(newMole)` gives us a version of `newMole.remove` with `this` explicitly set to `newMole`.